# Persistent jQuery Countdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown

We're trying to set up a countdown starting from 5 days. We manage to make it work using the code below. However, it refreshes back to 5 days when you reload the page. I was wondering how we can make it so that it doesn't reset back to 5 days when you refresh or reload the page. I have very minimal experience with Javascript and I'm lost on what to do next.

```
<html>
<body>
<span id="countdown" class="timer">7200</span>
<script type="text/javascript">

var first_time = true;
var countdownTimer;
var seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML * 60;
//alert(seconds);
if(!isNaN(seconds) && seconds > 0 ) {

    function timer() {

        if(first_time) {
            countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
            first_time = false;
        }

        var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
        var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
        var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
        var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = (days < 10 ? "0" : "") + days + ":" + (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + ":" + (remainingSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Completed";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }

    timer()

    //var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @user2753460! Hope you like it here. Have you considered:
1. Cookies, or
2. Local Storage?

Comment: Thank you. @PeterKA. I'm looking into cookies but I can't figure how it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check for web storage support and use it to store your counter; if no support store the counter in a cookie:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // You can use localStorate to store the seconds
    localStorage.setItem("seconds", secs);
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support.. use cookie
}
```

However at the start of your code, which runs when the page loads, read the counter and continue from where you left off:

```
var seconds;
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined" && localStorage.seconds) {
    seconds = localStorage.getItem("seconds");
} else if (typeof(Storage) === "undefined") {
    //read cookie (if using cookie)
} else {
    seconds = document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML * 60;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Ldtbu6ev/14/)